# Is workmanger need internet to trigger schedule job

Tags: android, kotlin, scheduled-tasks, android-workmanager

I developed alarm application where i used workmanager to schedule an alarm and create a notification when workmanager execute the work.
The issue i faced is, the notification is not generate when internet was diconnect. when the internet is connected the previous scheuled notification is generate.
My question is there is required internet to triger the work of workmanager.
Below my code...

Here is the code to schedule alarm

```
val delayInSeconds =(alarmCal.timeInMillis / 1000L) - (todayDateTime.timeInMillis / 1000L)
            createWorkRequest(title, message, reqCode, delayInSeconds)

private fun createWorkRequest(title: String,message: String,code: Int,timeDelayInSeconds: Long) {
    val myWorkRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<ReminderWorker>()
        .setInitialDelay(timeDelayInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .setInputData(
            workDataOf(
                "title" to title,
                "message" to message,
                "code" to code
            )
        )
        .addTag("Prayer_Alarm_$code")
        .build()

    WorkManager.getInstance(requireContext()).enqueue(myWorkRequest)
}
```

Here is the worker code...

```
class ReminderWorker(val context: Context, val params: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, params) {

private var title = ""
private var message = ""
private var requestCode = 0

override fun doWork(): Result {
    Log.d("myWorker", "Worker Triggered")
    title = inputData.getString("title").toString()
    message = inputData.getString("message").toString()
    requestCode = inputData.getInt("code", 0)

    NotificationHelper(context).createNotification(
        title,
        message,
        requestCode
    )

    setNextDateAlarm(requestCode, title, message)


    return Result.success()
}

private fun setNextDateAlarm(requestCode: Int, title: String, message: String) {
    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1)
    cal.time = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(pTime)
    Log.d("NotificationTime", "Notification Time: Title $title, Request Code: $requestCode ")
    val todayDateTime = Calendar.getInstance()
    val delayInSeconds = (cal.timeInMillis / 1000L) - (todayDateTime.timeInMillis / 1000L)
    createWorkRequest(title, message, requestCode, delayInSeconds)
}



private fun createWorkRequest(title: String, message: String, code: Int, timeDelayInSeconds: Long) {
    val myWorkRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<ReminderWorker>()
        .setInitialDelay(timeDelayInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .setInputData(
            workDataOf(
                "title" to title,
                "message" to message,
                "code" to code
            )
        )
        .addTag("Alarm_$code")
        .build()

    WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(myWorkRequest)
}
```